# Unable to install ssh2 lib for php on centos

Tags: centos, php

I'm trying to install the ssh2 lib on my centos os server as per this tutorial :
http://blog.dynamichosting.biz/2011/01/10/installing-ssh2-extension-for-php-on-centos-5/

Everything seems to go fine after I run the `pecl install -f ssh2` command until the last few lines of the responce I get  : `running: make
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: make failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have all of the necessary development tools installed ("make: command not found"). 'yum install make' will solve the immediate problem, but you're likely to run into trouble again -- make probably isn't the only thing missing. [This CyberCiti page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-install-gcc-c-c-compiler/) lists the packages you'll need to make sure you have installed, to give you the basic set of dev tools, as well as giving a description of how to go about installing them all at once.